# Change Parent Element's behaviour when child is hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML

What I want to do is to zoom effect when user hovers on **image** which I managed to do successfully by including another css class in javascript like:

```js
$(".featured-image .attachment-shop_catalog").addClass("otherClass");
```

```css
    .otherClass
    {
        display:inline-block;
        border:0;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -ms-transform: scale(1); 
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transform: scale(1);   
    
    }
    .otherClass:hover
    {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px #000000;
        z-index: 2;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5);   
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    .products li.product {
        background-color: #ecebeb !important;
        height: 10%
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
         <li class="product type-product">
             <a href="#" class="product-images">
                  <span class="feautured-image">
                      <img src="http://www.omstema.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/new-template.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog">
                  </span>
             </a>
          <li>
    </ul>
```

No problem so far. But what I want to do is, zoom **not just image** but the entire

```
<li>
```

item.

How can I do that? Any idea is appriated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no previous sibling selectors in CSS, you can only achieve this with javascript.

What you need to do is add an hover in and out event, cache your current hovered element as `$(this)` and use javascript to target on the parent elements

```
$(".attachment-shop_catalog").addClass("otherClass");

$(".otherClass").hover(function(){
   $(this).closest("li").addClass("otherClassParent");
    }, function(){
    $(this).closest("li").removeClass("otherClassParent");
});
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/BQvoNJ

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
jQuery( ".featured-image .attachment-shop_catalog" ).hover(
  function() {
    jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass("otherClass");
  }, function() {
    jQuery(this).parents('li').removeClass("otherClass");
  }
);

.otherClass
{
    display:inline-block;
    border:0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); 
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); 
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1.5);   

}
```

Comment: I now I can do that but what I want to do is to zoom <li> item "only" when <img> is hovered. Your solution, I can hover everything. @Xzandro